# RadioButton not working as it should

Tags: java, android

Could some take a look at the below and try and explain what I'm missing? I've used the below method before in an application and its worked perfectly. Im sure its something silly I have missed and would love to get someone to look over it...

I input the air volume and pressure and click on my RadioButton ForwardCBD. This should create a double power, this should then be outputted to the screen but instead it causes the app to crash out.

Any ideas?

```
EditText AirVolume, Pressure,FCBD,BCBD,BCDD;
TextView Power;
RadioGroup Fans;
RadioButton ForwardCBD, BackwardCBD, BackwardCDD;


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.car);

    AirVolume=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.AirVolume);
    Pressure=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.Pressure);

    Power=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.Power);

    ForwardCBD=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.ForwardCBD);
    BackwardCBD=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.BackwardCBD);
    BackwardCDD=(RadioButton)findViewById(R.id.BackwardCDD);

    Fans=(RadioGroup)findViewById(R.id.Fans);
    Fans.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

}   

public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup Fans, int aplication) {

    if (aplication==R.id.ForwardCBD){

        double airVolume = Double.parseDouble(AirVolume.getText().toString());
        double pressure = Double.parseDouble(Pressure.getText().toString());
        double fCBD = Double.parseDouble(FCBD.getText().toString());        
        double power = (airVolume * pressure) / (fCBD /100);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        Power.setText(df.format(power)+("W"));

    }
    if (aplication==R.id.BackwardCBD){

        double airVolume = Double.parseDouble(AirVolume.getText().toString());
        double pressure = Double.parseDouble(Pressure.getText().toString());
        double bCBD = Double.parseDouble(BCBD.getText().toString());        
        double power = (airVolume * pressure) / (bCBD /100);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        Power.setText(df.format(power)+("W"));

    }
    if (aplication==R.id.BackwardCDD){
        double airVolume = Double.parseDouble(AirVolume.getText().toString());
        double pressure = Double.parseDouble(Pressure.getText().toString());
        double bCDD = Double.parseDouble(BCDD.getText().toString());        
        double power = (airVolume * pressure) / (bCDD /100);
        DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat();
        Power.setText(df.format(power)+("W"));
    }

}   
}
```

See the LogCat below.

Not really sure how to present it in a decent format on here so sorry in advance!

```
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at com.test.will.CarSystems.onCheckedChanged(CarSystems.java:46)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at android.widget.RadioGroup.setCheckedId(RadioGroup.java:172)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at android.widget.RadioGroup.access$600(RadioGroup.java:52)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at android.widget.RadioGroup$CheckedStateTracker.onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup.java:342)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.setChecked(CompoundButton.java:128)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.toggle(CompoundButton.java:87)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at android.widget.RadioButton.toggle(RadioButton.java:75)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:99)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:14400)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4945)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
08-19 12:10:24.576: E/AndroidRuntime(11733):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Crash = LogCat stacktrace. Please guys, add the logcat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Where have you assigned components to FCBD,BCBD,BCDD; which are probably null pointers.

your calling

```
double fCBD = Double.parseDouble(FCBD.getText().toString());
```

But where have you defined/assigned FCBD  i.e.

```
FCBD=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.FCBD);
```

Otherwise, step through in debug mode and you will find that one of your properties is null, which your trying to call a method upon.

Comment: I knew it would be a silly error... Thanks for pointing out the obvious, you have save me from pulling out my hair over the next few hours stressing out over this.